# Outlook Calender entry in Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm working on a C# application that (among others) needs to be able to add new entries into an Outlook Calender. 
After looking up how to do this in Visual Studio , I found that this isn't possible in the Express version , that I was using , because of the missing templates.

But now I'm using Visual Studio Community. I've tried to use [this code from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268752.aspx) but that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing an import ? Or are Office add-ins also not supported in VS Community , like they were in VS Express ?

If so , is my best option still to use [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) ? Or am I overlooking something else ?

Answer (score 0):

The Community edition of Visual Studio 2013 corresponds to the Professional one. So, you can use VSTO for developing Office add-ins. You just need to install [Office dev tools](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2013).

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started developing an Outlook add-in.

Finally, you may consider a VSTO  based add-in as a regular .Net application where you can use all BCL classes and third-party components.